# Membership.ValidateUser always return false on IIS

Tags: iis, web-config, asp.net-membership, cassini

Membership.ValidateUser methods works on development server both(iis express and cassini).
But on my IIS (its publishing as an application on my development machine) It always return **false**.

Even user is approved,not locked and username and password are correct. There is no trace error. ?

**http request 1:**
davutg-pc:**6423**/BpmService/Login?userName=abc&password=0035

**result 1:**
           < boolean >**true**< /boolean >

**http request 2:** davutg-pc/BPM/BpmService/Login?userName=abc&password=0035

**result 2 :**< boolean > **false** < /boolean >

Here are my settings

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider"/>

<machineKey validationKey="E8B40EEA5A8EFC6F...key" decryptionKey="385..." validation="SHA1" />

<membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider"  hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
  <providers>
    <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider"  />
    <add type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, 
         PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
         name="MySQLMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="3"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         passwordFormat="Encrypted"/>
```

I compared machine.configs are the same Framework 64 and Framework.

It works on development server but on IIS always return false. I can **query different services** with IIS and no such problem.

**IN ADDITION:**
When I enter wrong password **"FailedPasswordAttemptCount" increased** for development server.
But it **doesn't change for IIS**. What's going wrong with IIS. I just call Membership.ValidateUser(user,pass)

Any suggestion will be appreciated !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved! Hope this will save someone's time.

The problem was the **application name.**

host:port/Service

host/**BPM**/Service

note:BPM is applicaton name you give it on IIS.

Membership encryption algorithm uses "ApplicatonName". When I setup applicaton I used BPM as application name. on development server the "name" return "/". But its "BPM" on IIS !

All my old passwords was generated with "/" appliacion name. So always provide an application Name. Read this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx) from Scott-Gu 's blog.

```
    public bool Login(string userName,string password)
    {
        var provider = Membership.Provider;
        string name = provider.ApplicationName;

        return Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password);
    }
```

//Wrong one

```
      <membership>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
                type="System...bla bla"
                connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
                enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                enablePasswordReset="true"
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
                requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                passwordFormat="Hashed"
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
                passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
                applicationName="/" //Wrong
            />
         </providers>
    </membership>
```

//Right one

```
          <membership>
                <providers>
                <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
                type="System.Web.Security.S.. bla bla"
                connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
                enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                enablePasswordReset="true"
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
                requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                passwordFormat="Hashed"
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
                passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
                applicationName="MyAPPNAME" //Well :)
            />
         </providers>
    </membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue and I couldn't fix it for two weeks.

Focus on the creation of the member using `CreateUser()`:

```
MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
MembershipUser member = 
Membership.CreateUser(TextBox_username.Text.Replace("'", "''"), 
           TextBox_password.Text.Replace("'", "''"), 
           TextBox_email.Text.Replace("'", "''"), null, null, true, out createStatus);
```

Check how the `CreateUser()` function is called. It should be like this.